# Angular map the object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mapping

I am trying to get only validationTypeId, validationType. But not working

```js
   this.accessDService.getValidationDetails().subscribe((result) => {
          this.accessDValidationDetails = result;
          if (!result) return;
          this.validationD = result.map(({ validationTypeId, validationType }) => ({ validationTypeId, validationType }));
```

And here my response body
{
"id": 32,
"validationTypeId": 2,
"accessDeviceId": 57,
"discountValue": 0,
"mins": 15,
"validationType": "Discount"
}

Comment: **1.** You cannot `return` from the subscription callback. **2.** What exactly would be the error in the implementation?

Comment: How can I return from subscription callback then? Error is property map doesn't exist on the "result"

Comment: **Q1.** Subscription callbacks are asynchronous. Variables cannot be returned from inside the subscription. You need to subscribe where the response is required. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921) for more info on async data. **Q2**. JS [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function could only be invoked upon arrays. Check if the `result` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get just one object from response you can't use `map` here.
You can use `map` only on arrays.

Just simple:

```
this.validationID = {validationTypeId: result.validationTypeId, validationType: result.validationType}
```

Edit:

Then maybe that will help:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators"; 

result.pipe(map(item => this.validationD.push({validationTypeId: item.validationTypeId, validationType: item.validationType})))
```

Comment: Edited answer, you can try it now

Comment: Thanks!! I tried like this simple way and it works. this.validationTypeLists = this.ValidationType.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }));